# HashMap key as id and value another entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hashmap

Can one mark the inner class of the key as Id and the inner class of value as another table? For instance I want to have 2 tables:

```
Keys (table 1)
id   | name      
1    | Some name 

Values (table 2)
id   | street      | key_id |...
1    | some street | 1      |...
```

But I want this using maps. So the objects would look something like:

```
@Entity
public class Key {
    //@???
    //@OneToMany (?)
    Map<KeyKey, Value> map;
}

//@Entity (?)
public class KeyKey {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Value {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    //@ManyToOne (?)
    private Key key;
    ...
}
```

Getters and setters included of course...

How is this done using annotations with spring/hibernate? Is this even supported? I tried finding the solution but none really answered the problem. The reason we want maps is because the real scenario has multiple map layers (map with object into another into another...), thus in the end allow us to quickly drill to the needed object without iterations.

Sorry if something is confusing, if it is, ask me and I'll correct the question.

P.S. My naming strategy is obviously flawless

Comment: you could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138694/key-value-column-name-overrides-when-mapping-java-util-map-with-jpa-annotation). also, if you have only 1 key entity per value and never the possibility of 2 keys being the same, then you don't need `@ManyToOne`, but why would you have the value pointing towards the map? it should point towards `KeyKey` as this is the value you want to map to

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thank you very much, I'll look it up!